# How to create a tooltip for multiple points in a scatterplot with d3

Tags: d3.js

I have a scatterplot created with d3. The circles/points are all the same size. The grid goes from 1-10 on both x and y axes. All points have x and y values of whole numbers (no decimals).

My problem is that I frequently have multiple data points with the same coordinates. Because the points are all the same size I can't tell how many points are at a single spot.

My points have tooltips, one for each data point. So, I was thinking that it's OK to show only a single point/circle if I can show a tooltip that contains information about all points with the same x/y coordinate. I can't think of a way to do that though because the tooltips seem to be generated for a single point, not "for all points at the same coordinate", or generated dynamically.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to make a fiddle, then we could do something on it.

Comment: Aggregate the overlapping points in the data before passing it to D3.

Comment: The code that generates the tooltip text for my points is here:
https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/blob/master/components/plot/scatterplot.js#L63

I'm thinking that instead of using the tasks directly, I will aggregate the points before rendering and then build the tooltip from that, which, happens to be exactly what @LarsKotthoff mentioned just above :)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I implemented the aggregation here: https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/commit/597477cccada35c0c8105211ed9c08042052d572#diff-59a863044c8d437ec2e58578a09aa2efR24

Now, however, because a single circle actually contains multiple data points, d3 doesn't seem to be able to update the plot when it should (when adding/removing/modifying a point).

Any thoughts on that part?

Comment: If you do the aggregation in the same way for the new data, it should work. What behaviour are you looking for exactly?

Comment: -When a point is added, and is the first point with its coordinates, a circle should be added to the grid.

- When a point is removed, and is the last point with its coordinates, the circle should be removed from the grid.

- When a point is added or removed and shares coordinates with other points, the color and tooltip of the circle should be updated.

- When a point is modified in a way that changes it's x/y coordinates, and it is the only point with its x/y coordinates, the circle should be moved to the new coordinates.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff In particular, right now new points aren't added after a new task is created and Application.Plotter.update() is called. enter(), exit(), etc. is called here in the code. https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/blob/master/components/plot/scatterplot.js#L287

Maybe I'm not calling it properly? I call update to handle changes for adds, deletions and modifications. Maybe I need three separate methods? Dunno.

Comment: You probably need a key function (the second argument to `.data()`) to tell D3 how to match data and elements.

Comment: Got it! The key function helped! Now it's adding/updating/removing exactly as I need it to! You rock @LarsKotthoff! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @LarsKotthoff mentioned, aggregating my data before rendering and adding a key function to identify each aggregate were the two steps needed to get everything working properly.

Comment: More info on this answer would be appreciated, so it can help the community. Your discussion in the comments reference links that no longer works, so it is useless to us...